# Count the number of vowels in a string

Tags: c, string, recursion

I simply want to count vowels in a string using recursion, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SETSIZ 10

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int is_empty(const char *set);
int is_element(char vowel, const char *set);
int is_vowel(const char *vowels, const char *set);

int main(void)
{
    int count = 0,i;
    char vowels[11] = {'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u', '\0'}, set[SETSIZ] = "mustafa";
    for(i=0;i<strlen(set);i++){
        if(is_vowel(vowels, set))
            count +=  1;
        }
    printf("%s has %d vowels",set, count);
    return(0);
}
int is_empty(const char *set)
{
    return(set[0] == '\0');
}
int is_element(char vowel, const char *set)
{
    int ans;
    if(is_empty(set))
        ans = FALSE;
    else if (vowel == set[0])
        ans = TRUE;
    else
        ans = is_element(vowel, &set[1]);
    return(ans);
}
int is_vowel(const char *vowels, const char *set)
{
    int ans, i = 0;

    if(is_empty(vowels))
        ans = FALSE;
    else if(is_element(vowels[0], set))
    {
        printf("**");
        ans = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("--");
        ans = is_vowel(&vowels[1], set);
        }

    return(ans);
}
```

Comment: In `main` You loop through `set` (which doesn't appear to exist in that scope), and always pass the same thing to `is_vowel`. You never use the loop counter `i`.

Comment: `set` is defined in the scroll region. I also thought it wasn't defined at first. To the OP: @paranoidgnu -- limit line length to 80 chars :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not loop through `set` as you probably want. Should be:

   ```
   if(is_vowel(vowels, &set[i]))
   ```
2. Your function `is_element()` is absolutely wrong, You can change it to:

   ```
   int is_element(char vowel, const char *set)
   {
       return (vowel == set[0]);
   }
   ```

or even pass characters instead of pointers to characters.

Answer (score 3):

There is problem in your is_vowel code.

```
int is_vowel(const char *vowels, const char *set)
{
int ans, i = 0;

if(is_empty(vowels))     //You are passing vowels which would never be empty.
    ans = FALSE;         //Replace it with set character pointer. 
//Rest of the code
```

The whole concept,applied seems to be wrong buddy .I would suggest you to rewrite the code.There are myriad number of mistakes in the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`, your for loop calls `is_vowel()` several times with the exact same arguments.

You may want to rewrite the function with a simpler protoyype:

```
/* int is_vowel(const char *vowels, const char *set); */
int is_vowel(const char *vowels, int ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>



int vowel(char str[],int k)
{
int count = 0;
while(str[k]!='\0')
{
    if(str[k] == 'a' || str[k] == 'e' || str[k] == 'i' || str[k] == 'o' || str[k] == 'u')
        return 1 + vowel(str,k+1);
    else
        return 0 +vowel(str,k+1);
}
return 0;
}
void main()
{
char x[50];
gets(x);
printf("%d",vowel(x,0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution to your problem:

```
#define VOWELS "aeiouAEIOU"

size_t vcount(const char *s)
{
        size_t i = 0;

        while (s && *s) {
                if (strchr(VOWELS, *s)) ++i;
                ++s;
        }

        return i;
}
```

It can easily be transformed into a recursive version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in python to count the number of vowels:

def vowels( s ):

```
if s == '':
    return 0   # no vowels in the empty string
elif s[0] in 'aeiouAEIOU':
    return 1 + vowels( s[1:] )
else:
    return 0 + vowels( s[1:] )
```

You can also use a variable such as vowel_list='aeiouAEIOU'